# How can I screen scrape what's in the inspect element area?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing, screen-scraping

I'm pretty new to all of this so I hope this makes sense. So there's a difference between the data held within the source code and the inspected elements. Is there any way that I can write a program to send a get request to a specific URL and then parse through the "inspect element" code?

Comment: Before any help, it would be helpful that you provide source code... Maybe you can read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @J.Piquard I can't post pictures right now since I'm a new member, so I posted everything on imgur at the link http://imgur.com/a/xlUjM

Comment: @J.Piquard in short, can I send a get request of a URL and get the inspect element code as a string

Comment: I will check your link later and update your post.